# Removing red line from the map

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

I am getting a red line/strip in the map. I am trying to remove this line. do any one know how to remove this?

I guess they are called something like bus routes. It appears along with the yellow border that connects the geopoints.

I have set,

```
    objMapView.setTraffic(false);
    objMapView.setSatellite(false);
```

Does any one has the answer for this?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of it? Are you doing any custom drawing or using overlays?

Comment: I don't have the enough reputation to post the screenshot...:( Yes I am drawing a balloon like overlay(as in iPhone)

Comment: Then post a link to it on an image site. Also post the draw methods for your mapview and overlays if you have implemented them

Comment: Here I have posted the image, please check it  https://picasaweb.google.com/112204717955298385514/14November2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue finally. I need to call invalidate() after I set traffic as false.

Here is how it should be

```
    objMapView.setTraffic(false);
    objMapView.invalidate();
```